# Unable to catch TweepError exception

Tags: python-3.x, twitter, error-handling, exception, tweepy

I tried to catch TweepError exception in while - try - except loop but unsuccessful. The following code keeps stop running when TweepError/ RateLimitError occuring.

```
    import tweepy
    import time
    name_set = ('name1','name2','name3')
    result = []
    for screen_name in name_set:
        while True:
           profile = api.get_user(screen_name = screen_name)
           try:
               print('collecting user %s'%screen_name)
               result.append(profile)
               break
           except tweepy.RateLimitError:
               print('sleep 15 minutes')
               sleep(900)
               continue
           except tweepy.TweepError as e:
               print(e)
               print('Account %s'%screen_name)
               break
           else:
               print('Account %s'%screen_name)
               break
```

> TweepError
>
> TweepError: [{'message': 'User not found.', 'code': 50}]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put a API call statement in the `try` block to catch a exception:

```
try:
    profile = api.get_user(screen_name = screen_name)
    print('collecting user %s'%screen_name)
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you! the exceptions are successfully catched.