# How to fix this "ImportError: cannot import name 'TweepError' from ..."?

Tags: python, tweepy

The line given below:

```
from tweepy import API, Stream, OAuthHandler, TweepError
```

generates ImportError such as:
`ImportError: cannot import name 'TweepError' from 'tweepy'`

I have tried: `from tweepy.errors import TweepError` ,however it stills generates error as:
`ImportError: cannot import name 'TweepError' from 'tweepy.errors'`.

What is it that I am missing here?

Comment: Looking at the source code, I don't see `TweepError` or `TweepyError` defined. Are you sure that's the right thing you want to import?

Comment: Obligatory links to [`tweepy/__init__.py`](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/master/tweepy/__init__.py#L20) and [`tweepy/errors.py`](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/master/tweepy/errors.py), as well as their [exceptions documentation](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/latest/exceptions.html)

Comment: I agree with the 1st comment of yours, and also looked through links which you have posted. I see "TweepError" has been used for exception handling like in this Stackoverflow post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45897600/unable-to-catch-tweeperror-exception. So I am looking to use this code snippet:                                                                
   `from tweepy.errors import (BadRequest, Forbidden, HTTPException, NotFound, TooManyRequests,TweepyException, TwitterServerError, Unauthorized
)` from your 1st link (i.e. tweepy/__init__.py)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TweepError has been replaced with TweepyException since the 4.0.0 (see [the changelog](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/changelog.html#version-4-0-0)).

So use `from tweepy.errors import TweepyException` (or `from tweepy import TweepyException`).

And replace `TweepError` with `TweepyException` in your code (or with a more specific exception).